# How to ignore values in a 2D array when performing calculations

Tags: c#

Given any 2D array ignore the smallest and largest values in each array (if there are multiple occurrences of the smallest/largest value only ignore one). Then calculate the sum of the remaining values.

```
int[,] scores = {
                          { 5, 8, 9, 3, 8, 5},
                          { 3, 9, 6, 3, 9, 5, 7}
                         };
```

The total of the first array would return 26
The total of the second array would return 30

Store each of these totals.

Comment: Do you really want to exclude the item, or just to calculate the sum by above criteria? Also, how does sorting(which was mentioned in the title) is related?

Comment: This is really not a place to post homework question and expect to get answers written for you.

Comment: I had sorting cause I believed a solution could be to sort the array into ascending order then ignore the first and last values when summing the array. And no the item does not need to be excluded if the results can be calculated to the above criteria. Just not quite sure how I can tackle this

Comment: I suggest you to start thinking on how to solve your homework, try to write down some code and if your have any concrete issues, then you can post a question with some progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt you are question is on `MultiDimensional` array or Array of Arrays (`Jagged Arrays`).  You *cannot* have different `dimensions` in `MultiDimensional` arrays.

So I assume you have Array of Arrays, now you could do this.

```
    int[][]  numbers2 = new int[][]
    {
        new int[] {1, 4,5,6, 10}, 
        new int[] {1,-2,3, 10, 1, }, 
        new int[] {-7,-8,-9, -1, 0}
    };

    var sum_array =numbers2.Select(x => x.OrderBy(c=>c)
                                         .Skip(1)
                                         .Take(x.Length-2)
                                         .Sum(c=>c)     
                                  );
```

**Output:**

```
  15,5,-16
```

in case, if you want to deal with `Multidimensional` arrays, do this.

```
    int[,]  numbers = new int[3,5]
    {
        {1, 4,5,6, 10}, 
        {1,-2,3, 10, 1, }, 
        {-7,-8,-9, -1, 0}
    };


    var row_sum  = numbers.Cast<int>()      
    .Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Index / (numbers.GetUpperBound(1) +1))
    .Select(x => x.OrderBy(c=>c.Value).Skip(1).Take(numbers.GetUpperBound(1)-1).Sum(c=>c.Value))
    .ToArray();
```

Both cases you get same output.

Check [`example`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pucXBg)